# How can a document claim it's persisted, when a count on the class returns 0?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How can a document claim `foo.persisted? == true`, when `foo.class.count == 0`?
More importantly, how can I get the document to truly persist?

Update: calling `Mongo::Foo.create()` from the controller does increment the count. That is expected. Calling `create`, or `new` and `save`, from within a separate module/class does **not** increment the count.

Update: I have tried changing `new`/`save` calls to `create`

Update: I have also tried `@foo_class.with(collection: "mongo_foos").create`

```
[42] pry(#<FoosController>)> foo.class
=> Mongo::Foo
[43] pry(#<FoosController>)> foo.persisted?
=> true
[44] pry(#<FoosController>)> Mongo::Foo.count
=> 0
[47] pry(#<FoosController>)> foo.id
=> "5081a1a786ddc8e035000021"
[48] pry(#<FoosController>)> foo
=> #<Mongo::Foo _id: 5081a1a786ddc8e035000021, _type: nil, foo_daddy_id: nil, old_foo_daddy_id: 219, member_id: "F008AR", unix_time: nil, date_time: 2012-10-19 13:50:54 UTC, submitted: nil, json: nil>
```

Here's how the document class is defined:

```
module Mongo
  class Foo
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :foo_daddy_id
    field :old_foo_daddy_id, type: Integer
    field :member_id,  type: String
    field :unix_time,  type: Integer
    field :date_time,  type: DateTime
    field :submitted,  type: Integer
    field :json,       type: Hash

    belongs_to :foo_daddy, class_name: "Mongo::FooDaddy"
    embeds_many :foo_dumplings, class_name: "Mongo::FooDumpling"

  end
end
```

The doc is being created with `foo.new(params); foo.save`:

```
module FooThingy
  module Foo
    class Create < ::FooThingy::Base

      def initialize(options)
        # Sets instance variables used below
      end

      def execute!
        @foo = @foo_class.new({
          date_time: DateTime.strptime(@params["submitted_timestamp"], "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"),
          member_id: (@params[:member_id].present? ? @params[:member_id] : nil),
          old_foo_daddy_id: @params[:old_foo_daddy_id]
        })

        embed_foo_dumplings

        if @foo.save
          return FooThingy::Result.new(success: true, data: { foo: @foo })
        else
          return FooThingy::Result.new(success: false, data: { foo: @foo })
        end
      end

      private
      def embed_foo_dumplings
        # Embeds foo_dumplings
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Here's where I call that module to create the document:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    foo_creator = FooThingy::Foo::Create.new(params: params, foo_class: Mongo::Foo)
    foo = foo_creator.execute!
    foo = foo.data[:foo]
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

Comment: have tried changing `@foo_class.new` to `@foo_class.create`... `Mongo::Foo.count` still returns 0

Comment: Note: If I call Mongo::Foo.create() in the controller, Mongo::Foo.count will increment. Saving the record from FooThingy::Foo::Create returns a document, but does not increment the count on Mongo::Foo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem, I think, is less interesting than it appears.  I've modified my `config/mongoid.yml` to specify a new database, and everything behaves as expected. Problem was likely due to limitations on 32-bit MongoDB installations.